# How do I convert python long into c unsigned int?

Tags: python, thrift, type-conversion, unsigned-integer

I am trying to make a thrift IDL call from python. The thrift data type of one variable is I32.
I need to send values between 0 and 2^32-1. For values between 2^31 and 2^32-1 python converts them to long. So, I get an error saying 'integer out of range for 'i' format code' for these values. I tried converting to ctypes.c_uint32. It did not work.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried using NumPy?

Comment: @salmanwahed: Thrift is an RPC framework and entirely orthogonal to NumPy.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Python problem, it's a misunderstanding on your part what numbers fit in a `i32` field.

From [Thrift: The Missing Guide](http://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/):

> Note that Thrift **does not support unsigned integers** because they have no direct translation to native (primitive) types in many of Thrift’s target languages.

and from the [Thrift Types documentation](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/types):

> Note the **absence of unsigned integer types**. This is due to the fact that there are no native unsigned integer types in many programming languages.

Emphasis mine.

Bottom line is that values of 2^31 and over don't fit in an unsigned `i32` 32-bit int. Use the `i64` type instead if you need to use values over 2^31-1 up to 2^63-1.

Comment: "Bottom line is that values of 2^31 and over don't fit in an unsigned int." Yeah, this should be the answer to focus on.

Comment: @ericchiang: And my research into Thrift shows that that framework doesn't support unsigned integers..

Comment: @MartijnPieters ist right. It is that way, and that's exactly the reason.